# Filter Data On Spring and Fetch in React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, backend

I'm building a Spring backend to use with a React frontend. We are building a products app and would like to filter in two brands for our hackathon purposes. The problem is, I can't get the desired filtered data and instead get everything cause I got some conditional statements in our ProductController. The data comes from a MongoDB database.

Again, my purpose is to figure out how can I fetch data from only two brands.

First, here's our ProductService.

```
package goodsamaritan.beauty;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    public List<Product> allProducts() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Product> findByBrand(List<String> brands) {
        List<Product> products = allProducts();
        System.out.println("All products: " + products);
        if (brands != null && !brands.isEmpty()) {
            products = products.stream()
                    .filter(product -> brands.contains(product.getBrand().toLowerCase()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return products;
    }

    public Optional<Product> singleProduct(int id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Secondly, this is what we have in the ProductController:

```
package goodsamaritan.beauty;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/products")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;
    @GetMapping
    public List<Product> getProducts(@RequestParam(value = "brands", required = false) List<String> brandProducts) {
        if (brandProducts == null || brandProducts.isEmpty()) {
            return productService.allProducts();
        } else {
            return productService.findByBrand(brandProducts);
        }
    }

    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(productService.allProducts(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Product>> getSingleProduct(@PathVariable int id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Product>>(productService.singleProduct(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Third, here's the React frontend's Products Component. There are commented lines of code cause I've been trying different options.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from '../api/axiosConfig'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Products() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   api.get("/api/v1/products", {
  //     params: {
  //       brand: ['clinique', 'smashbox']
  //     }
  //   })
  //   .then((response) => {
  //     setProducts(response.data);
  //   });
  // }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    api.get("/api/v1/products?brand%5B%5D=clinique&brand%5B%5D=smashbox")
      .then((response) => {
        setProducts(response.data);
      });
  }, []);

  if (!products) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div className="mx-auto sm:py-12 sm:px-6 lg:max-w-14xl lg:px-8">
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900">Our Products</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-10 gap-x-8 sm:grid-cols-1 px-3 lg:grid-cols-4 px-28 xl:gap-x-24">
      {products?.map((product) => ( 
        <div key={product.id}>      
          <div class="min-h-100 aspect-w-1 aspect-h-80 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-gray-200 group-hover:opacity-75 lg:aspect-none lg:h-100">
            <img src={product.image_link} alt={product.imageAlt} class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center lg:h-full lg:w-full"/>
          </div> 
          <div class="mt-4 flex justify-between">
            <h3 class="text-md text-gray-700">
            <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`} >
                <span aria-hiddden="true" class="absolute inset-0"/>
                  {product.name}
              </Link>
            </h3>
            {/* <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{product.product_colors}</p> */}
          </div>
          <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{product.brand}</p>
          <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">$ {product.price}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

The last error I got when I tried without any conditional statement to instead get all products was `Cannot invoke "java.util.List.contains(Object)" because "brand" is null`.

How can I solve this issue and get just the two brands we want?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
public List<Product> getProducts(@RequestParam(value = "brands", required = false) List<String> brandList) {
    //...
}
```

We need a param `brands`, and that type is `List<String>`, you can do like this:

```
/api/v1/products?brand=a,b,c,d,e
```

Then the `brandList` while be:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

---

what you was use:

```
/api/v1/products?brand%5B%5D=clinique&brand%5B%5D=smashbox
```

use `decodeURI` to decode that, it will be:

```
decodeURI("/api/v1/products?brand%5B%5D=clinique&brand%5B%5D=smashbox")
'/api/v1/products?brand[]=clinique&brand[]=smashbox'
```

that will not work

Comment: I'm not sure if the way I worded this issue is confusing. More than a brand list, I want to filter data from two particular brands. This looks more like an array of the brands as far as I understood the answer.

Comment: @Norbert Do you mean you have a set of data with all brands and you want to filter out only the two brands you pass through the interface parameters?

Comment: That's correct. I'd like to filter all products from just two brands.

Comment: You have already filtered, use products.stream().filter